# URL parsing and sessions in Reservation system

Tags: php, url, session

I am creating a flight/hotel reservation system like farecompare.com Farecompare parse values to other sites and create sessions other sites too. Anyone tell me how they create sesssions in it. I can parse url but i am not able to create sessions.

```
public function flight($depart, $return, $from, $to, $type, $class,
                       $adults, $seniors, $children) {

    $dep = explode("/", $depart);
    $ret = explode("/", $return);

    if ($type == 'RoundTrip') {
        $expurl = 'http://www.expedia.co.in/Flights-Search?trip=' .
                  strtolower($type) . '&leg1=from%3A' . $from .
                  '%29%2Cto%3A' . $to .
                  '%29%2Cdeparture%3A' . $dep[1] .
                  '/'.$dep[0].'/'.$dep[2].
                  'TANYT&leg2=from%3A' . $to .
                  '%29%2Cto%3A' . $from .
                  '%29%2Cdeparture%3A' .
                  $ret[1].'/'.$ret[0].'/'.$ret[2] .
                  'TANYT&passengers=children%3A' . $children .
                  '%2Cadults%3A' . $adults .
                  '%2Cseniors%3A' . $seniors .
                  '%2Cinfantinlap%3AY&options=cabinclass%3Aeconomy'. 
                  '%2Cnopenalty%3AN%2Csortby%3Aprice&mode=search';

        echo '<a href = "' . $expurl . '" target = "_blank">Expedia</a>';
    } else {
        $type = 'oneway';

        $expurl = 'http://www.expedia.co.in/Flights-Search?trip='.
                  strtolower($type) . '&leg1=from%3A' . $from .
                  '%29%2Cto%3A' . $to . '%29%2Cdeparture%3A' .
                  $dep[1].'/'.$dep[0].'/'.$dep[2] .
                  'TANYT&passengers=children%3A' . $children .
                  '%2Cadults%3A' . $adults .
                  '%2Cseniors%3A' . $seniors .
                  '%2Cinfantinlap%3AY&options=cabinclass%3Aeconomy'. 
                  '%2Cnopenalty%3AN%2Csortby%3Aprice&mode=search';
        echo '<a href = "' . $expurl . '" target = "_blank">Expedia</a>';
    }
}
```

I worked on Expedia by parsing url to get data but there are other sites like cheapoait, travelocity etc which uses sessions. How to create sessions?

Comment: I read your question, but I still can't see how sessions have anything to do with parsing other site data into your own site, or what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, I do see what you are trying to achieve, but it gets really confusing because you keep mentioning "sessions", and you don't provide any code relevant to your task.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume they store it in the cookies.

Comment: I know about session/cookie, i want to know what they save or how they randomly create sessions on different sites

Comment: @Burhan Do you mean how they "move" data from other sites, without you seeing them in the URL? How about `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

We can not access session data of other domain on our site. Data transfer done using web services SOAP OR REST in form of XML. That can be retrieved on other domain and store in session and cookies and use for calculation in website.